# Unable to set values to the data members of Datacontract embedded inside Member Contract from client

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a message contract as under

```
 [MessageContract]
    public class PartnerLogViewRequest
    {
        [MessageBodyMember(Order = 0)]
        public PartnerLogView PartnerViewLog { get; set; }
    }
```

And the data contract as under

```
[DataContract]
    public class PartnerLogView
    {
        public int PartnerViewLogId { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public string ClientIPAddress { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    }
```

So the data contract is exposed as a property from the message contract.

Now I have created the client proxy. And want to access the properties of the data contract but could not...

My attempt

```
 PartnerLogViewRequest request = new PartnerLogViewRequest();
 request.PartnerViewLog.ExtensionData
```

Instead of properties to appear, some "ExtensionData" is coming...

What I am missing and how to assign values to the properties of **PartnerLogView**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try putting `[DataMember]` attribute over `public` properties of `PartnerLogView` class, and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the [DataMember] attribute. I am not sure if you missed it in your query, but you havent created an object for PartnerLogView.

```
PartnerLogView partnerLogView = new PartnerLogView();

partnerLogView.PartnerViewLogId =0;
...
...

PartnerLogViewRequest request = new PartnerLogViewRequest();
request.PartnerViewLog=partnerLogView;
```